# How to automatically convert zoompan filter's private fps to input video's fps?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have a 24 fps video, I'm trying to use the zoompan filter in my video and I'm having trouble setting the filter's private fps. If you set the fps in the zoompan filter to `fps=30`, the video and audio will be out of sync. The speed of the output video increases but still the audio is at its original speed. Setting the fps in the filter to `fps=24` will solve the problem but I have many videos with different fps and I don't want to set the fps in the filter for each video separately.

Is there a way for zoompan filter's private fps to automatically detect the fps in the input video and keep the fps of the video?

Even if I added `-r 30` to the beginning and end of the command line, it didn't work.

```
ffmpeg-y -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(it*25,42),10),min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.02,1.5),min(max(zoom,pzoom)-0.0065,1.5))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:fps=30 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: I think there is no such option. You may [get the FPS using FFprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35404908/4926757), put it in a variable (like $FPS in Linux shell), and use the variable in FFmpeg command (like `fps=$FPS`). Note that storing stdout output in a variable is not so trivial, and it is shell dependent.

Comment: If you are happy to set the frame rate to 30fps for all your inputs, add a framerate filter at the start of the filter chain. `[0:v]framerate=30[FR];[FR]zoompan`.... Bare in mind all other calculations in your script must be based on 30fps.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing, Rotem. @Sark It worked great, I appreciate your help.